# Word for a conspiracy/cabal/syndicate/etc in which a proper subset of actors are unaware of their roles

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (or, if necessary, a concise phrase) which has the same rough pejorative meaning as the words listed in the title, i.e. a group of actors who work together to achieve a (usually malicious) goal through subversive and nefarious means. However, each of those words imply, at least to my ears, that every actor in the group is a knowledgable and willing participant in the scheme. I am concerned with an alternate case, in which a proper subset (some, but not all) of the actors in the scheme are unaware and proceeding honestly, and yet their actions are a necessary contribution to the successful completion of the group's goals. The phrase "unwitting conspirator" or stating they provided "unwitting assistance" are commonplace for referring to the role of the honest actor specifically, but I'm looking for a term for the entire group which implies only some of the actors are actively malicious, and are "using" other members of the group for their own purposes.

This type of structure is a common part of team con/heist movies, in which the con artists "use" some honest actor acting as their job intends for a necessary component of their plot. For example in the movie *The Sting* ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sting#Plot)), a police officer is told by someone he believes to be a federal marshal (but is actually one of the con artists) to remove the mark from the scene of the con, thereby allowing the conspirators to escape.

Comment: The nearest I can offer is a 'set-up'. P.S. check your spelling of 'necessary' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question: *a sting*.

> In law enforcement, a sting operation is a deceptive operation designed to catch a person committing a crime. A typical sting will have a law-enforcement officer or cooperative member of the public play a role as criminal partner or potential victim and go along with a suspect's actions to gather evidence of the suspect's wrongdoing.

[...]

> The term "sting" was popularized by the 1973 Robert Redford and Paul Newman movie *The Sting*, although the film is not about a police operation: it features two grifters and their attempts to con a mob boss out of a large sum of money. –*Sting operation*, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_operation)

'A sting' implies at least one party that is *not* a willing participant. Conspirators, cabals, syndicates and law enforcement all use stings.

---

Another word is *them*. As with any group, there's *us* and *them*; you're either in or you're out. If you're out, you're *not privy*.

In closing, allow me to state that any *proper* conspiracy/cabal/syndicate/etc will have people that are unaware of their roles (and that this distinction is unnecessary; it's intrinsic). Members are often unaware of (or disregard) the hierarchy within their own sect: (honor among thieves, there is not)

*No, no, no... I kill the bus driver.* –[The Dark Knight](https://www.google.com/search?q=no%20no%20no%20i%20kill%20the%20bus%20driver&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

---

The policeman in *The Sting* who was duped is a *patsy*.

**patsy** pat·sy /ˈpatsē/ noun, North American, informal –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=patsy%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> a person who is easily taken advantage of, especially by being cheated or blamed for something.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patsy) offers the word *sucker*.

Comment: I assume you're excluding dupes from "people ... unaware." In that case, "proper" conspiracies may include only people aware of their roles in the enterprise.  In the prison breakout in upstate New York, there were four co-conspirators -- the two escapees and two prison employees whom smuggled tools for the escape.  No one of the four could have been unaware of his or her role in the escape.  The ex-governor of Virginia and his wife were convicted of conspiracy simply by agreeing with each other to accept gifts to promote an acquaintance's business.

Comment: The line here is rather fine.  Am I an unwitting participant in a conspiracy to hide someone in a crowd if I'm just a member of the crowd?  Did I unwittingly participate in the governor's conspiracy because I voted for him?  What if I'm simply one of billions of people who value the sorts of gifts that were given, thus making them worth something?

Comment: @deadrat - 'Dupe' almost warrants it's own answer (good one). Every sting has at least one *dupe*, usually more than just the one *mark*. If your example was a movie, the escapees would turn state's evidence against the guards as part of an extreme scheme to thwart the evil warden, culminating with the governor being impeached.

Comment: @Mazura - Generally I agree with the second component of your comment. My issue is not that a conspiracy et. al. utilizing unwilling participation of honest actors feels in any way an unnatural part of the usage of those terms. However, it feels unwieldy when enumerating the different actors and their roles to have to very directly and explicitly note the unwilling nature of those honest actors at essentially every turn, which I find myself needing to do due to the instinctive implication of active involvement I feel those words convey.

Comment: @Mazura - As for the first section of your answer, the term _sting_ to me implies a discrete moment at which the plans of the conspiracy et. al. come to a head, and which leave the honest participants in a lurch (just as a police sting leaves the criminals in a lurch). I'm looking for a term which could necessarily imply a more continous action where the honest actor may never become aware of the role they played. The idea is that the legitimate actions which the actor is entrusted with executing (and which they do so propely) is a necessary component of the conspiracy.

Comment: @SamuelJudson - *I'm looking for a term for the entire group which implies only some of the actors are actively malicious:* crooked? or are you looking for what to call *that* guy who's *none the wiser?* a sheep; pawn? Or the term for companies like [Evil Corp](http://mrrobot.wikia.com/wiki/E_Corp)? (your title does a good job of that). {grasping at straws here, one more try} You want a single word for *the victim of a ruse*? I'd have to go with *sucker*. (see edit)

Comment: @Mazura - I'm looking for a term for the entire group which means the goal of the group is to accomplish a malicious action through subterfuge, yet the composition of the group is partially complicit actors knowledgable (to some extent) of the existence, ends, and means of the group, and partially honest actors being used by the other members of the group. The terms I mentioned in the title imply (to me at least) that the group is composed of only the former. They may utilize the latter, but I don't think the terms imply the latter actors are "members" of the group.

Comment: @Mazura - For a term for those honest actors themselves, I don't like sucker or mark, since they imply the honest actors are at a loss due to the actions of the group, or patsy, which implies they are easily susceptible to being fooled. In the specific case motivating this question, the actors aren't fooled or do anything wrong. They just play a role in a system which the group is taking advantage of. Unwilling participant has the right tone to me.  Also, I wouldn't be surprised if no one can come up with such a term or phrase, it would just be sufficently useful for my purposes for me to ask.

Comment: @SamuelJudson - These actors are not members of the group; they're *unwitting accomplices*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28918/discussion-between-mazura-and-samuel-judson).

Answer (score 0):

Dupes - The subset of actors who perform their role in the conspiracy, but are not aware of their role could be called as "Dupes"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dupe

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.